# building a list and sending to an AJAX method

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am building a list from an array that I then pass via AJAX using the data parameter.

Everything looks good when I write out my list to the console, but my AJAX method doesn't like it.

```
for (i = 0; i < carList.length; i++) {

    var carData = { "data": { "CarId": '"' + CarList[i] + '"', "PassengerCar": "true", "Automatic":"true" } };
    console.log(carData);
}

$.ajax({
dataType: "json",
data: carData 
....
```

Am I doing something improper?

Thanks

Comment: What is your complete AJAX code? You need to specify url.

Comment: You're not building anything, you're overwriting the same variable multiple times!

Comment: @999cm999 Use Fiddler.  It will return a specific error from the server if the request fails. On top of adeneo, you delcare the carData in the scope of the for loop so when the loop exits it doesn't exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var carData = {};

for (i = 0; i < carList.length; i++) {

    carData["data_"+i] = {
                          CarId       : CarList[i], 
                          PassengerCar: true, 
                          Automatic   : true
                          };

}

$.ajax({
    url     : 'someurl.php',
    dataType: 'json', //expects returned data from server to be JSON
    data    : carData
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```